# Count number of unique values in two columns by group

Tags: r

I have a data frame with IDs for web page ('Webpage'), department ('Dept') and employee ('Emp_ID'):

```
df <- data.frame(Webpage = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222), 
                 Dept = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103), 
                 Emp_ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)) 

#   Webpage Dept Emp_ID
# 1     111  101      1
# 2     111  101      1
# 3     111  101      2
# 4     111  102      3
# 5     222  102      4
# 6     222  103      4
```

I want to know how many unique individual has seen the different webpages.

[image]

For e.g. in the following dataset webpage 111 has been seen by three individual (unique combination of Dept and emp ID). So webpage 111 has been seen by emp_ID 1,2 and 3 in Dept 101 and 102. Similarly webpage 222 has been seen by two different individual.

My first attempt is:

```
nrow(unique(data[ , c("Dept", "Emp_ID)]))
```

Using `unique` I can do for *one* web page, but can someone please suggest how I can calculate this for all web pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(Webpage = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222), 
                 Dept = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103), 
                 Emp_Id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4))
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Webpage) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(Dept, Emp_Id))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Webpage     n
#>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1     111     3
#> 2     222     2

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(n = uniqueN(paste0(Dept, Emp_Id))), by = Webpage]
#>    Webpage n
#> 1:     111 3
#> 2:     222 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: An alternative `data.table` solution would be `df[ , .(n = uniqueN(.SD)), by = Webpage]`

Comment: Or more explicit about which columns to include in `.SD`: `df[ , .(n = uniqueN(.SD)), by = Webpage, .SDcols = c("Dept", "Emp_Id")]`, if there are additional columns which should not be considered in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

For each `Webpage` count unique number based on two columns using `duplicated`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Webpage) %>%
  summarise(n_viewers = sum(!duplicated(cur_data())))

#  Webpage n_viewers
#    <dbl>     <int>
#1     111         3
#2     222         2
```

**data**

Provide data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy rather than an image.

```
df <- data.frame(Webpage = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222), 
                 Dept = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103), 
                 Emp_Id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope `aggregate` can help

```
> aggregate(cbind(n_viewer = Emp_Id) ~ Webpage, unique(df), length)
  Webpage n_viewer
1     111        3
2     222        2
```